# Is there a control for a .Net WinForm app that will display HTML

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .net (3.5) WinForms application and want to display some html on one of the forms. Is there a control that I can use for this?

Comment: Do you need to display it as rendered or just as text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep sure is, the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at the WebBrowser control but couldn't work out how to assign (set) the HTML to it...?

EDIT: Found it - Document Text

Comment: `webBrowser.DocumentText = htmlString`

Answer (score 1):

what about the browser control? a bit heavy, but at least you'll get an accurate rendering.